# Android emulator will not scroll

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator

I'm targeting Android 4.2.2 level 17 with Eclipse 4.3.1.v20130911-1000.  I've created an AVD that emulates an Intel Atom (x86) with [HAXM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1554099/why-is-the-android-emulator-so-slow).  Here's what it looks like...

[image]

And, here's a snippet of my activity code...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="1" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/bannerImage"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:contentDescription="@string/banner"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/logo" >

</ImageView>
    <CheckBox android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:id="@+id/expiredcheckBox" android:text="@string/show_me_expired_content"></CheckBox>
    <TextView android:id="@+id/textLabel1" android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="@string/category_"></TextView>
    <Spinner android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:id="@+id/comboBox" android:entries="@array/Spinner_array" android:prompt="@string/spinnerPrompt"></Spinner>

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:visibility="visible" >

        <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/linearLayoutScroll" android:orientation="vertical"></LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

The activity code dynamically adds TextView objects to the "linearLayoutScroll" within the ScrollView.  I start the emulator, debug my program, but, the emulator will not scroll with the middle mouse button.  I've had this problem before, but, for the life of me, I don't remember how to resolve it.  Can someone shed some light on it?

Comment: Hum.. with the middle mouse button? Did you try to scroll by pressing with the left mouse button? I'm not sure to clearly understand your problem.

Comment: Eh, the middle mouse button does nothing in an AVD AFAIK. Like Fllo said above, just use your left mouse button and while pressing it, drag the mouse up and down to scroll.

Comment: @Fllo I'm trying to scroll my view with the middle mouse button. The scroll bar displays but nothing scrolls.

Comment: @ChuongPham I'll try that and report back.

Comment: As suggested, holding the left button while moving the mouse will scroll.  I'm not sure why wheel scroll is not supported.

Comment: Well, Google can provide you with this answer as to why they don't support wheel scroll. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been able to resolve my scrolling problem by downloading and installing [GenyMotion](http://www.genymotion.com/) android emulator.